# $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we compute the integral ?

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} dz$$

Actual problem asks to compute:
$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{z^n}{\sqrt{z^2+1}} dz$$

To compute this I need to solve the integral: $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} dz$ which I'm clueless about how to do.

Comment: Try the substitution $z = e^{it}$

Comment: In the integral of interest, there is a holomorphic branch of the integrand on the circle of integration. In the reformulated integral, the contour crosses a branch cut, so its value isn't well-defined. That is, it appears you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrization of the unit circle:

$$z=e^{it}\implies dz=ie^{it}dt\implies \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{\sqrt z}=i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}dt}{e^{it/2}}=$$

$$=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it/2}dt=\left.2e^{it/2}\right|_0^{2\pi}=2(-1-1)=-4$$

Comment: Joan, you tacitly cut the plane along the non-negative real axis to arrive at this answer.  So, the answer is contingent on the choice of definition of $\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you. Yes...and no. Yes, because I've tacitly chosen the  negative of the usual branch for the square root (i.e., choosing the negative root for positive real numbers), so yes: otherwise that complex integral, to begin with, wouldn't be formally well defined. But "no" because, after all, when doing the parametrization we overcome that difficulty even without explicitly addressing it....I'm interested in you opinion, please.

Comment: Parameterizing as you have done, you have assumed that $0 \le \arg(z)<2\pi$.  Therefore, you have cut the plane such that the cut starts at $z=0$, passes through $z=1$, and extends to $z=\infty$.  Suppose instead that you selected $-\pi < t\le \pi$.  What answer would you have obtained?

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you. Bottom line, the branch must be chosen so as to make sense of the complex (line) integral. After that, substitute accordingly and forget it all. For example, had I chosen the negative real axis as branch, then I couldn't have chosen the substitution as I did, but rather, perhaps, $\;-\pi<t<\pi\;$ , say.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With the *branch-cut*
$\ds{z^{-1/2} = \verts{z}^{-1/2}
\expo{-\ic\,\mathrm{arg}\pars{z}/2}\,,\
\phi - 2\pi < \,\mathrm{arg}\pars{z} < \phi\,,\
z \not= 0}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over \root{z}}} & =
-\int_{1}^{0}{\expo{\ic\phi}\dd r \over \root{r}\expo{\ic\phi/2}} -
\int_{0}^{1}{\expo{\ic\pars{\phi - 2\pi}}\dd r \over
\root{r}\expo{\ic\pars{\phi - 2\pi}/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\expo{\ic\phi/2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd r \over \root{r}} +
\expo{\ic\phi/2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd r \over \root{r}}
\\[3mm] & = 2\expo{\ic\phi/2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd r \over \root{r}} =
\color{#f00}{4\expo{\ic\phi/2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first to compute the second. Choose the branch of $\sqrt{z}$ such that $\sqrt{1}=1$ then for $\lvert z \rvert > 1$ $$\frac{z^n}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}=\frac{z^n}{z\sqrt{1+z^{-2}}} = z^{n-1}(1+z^{-2})^{-\frac12}$$ which is a single valued holomorphic function. Expand this function as a Laurent series and use Cauchy's integral formula to compute your second integral.